# SQL Найти количество непрерывно повторяющихся значений

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица readed_books

| id | author_id | message | is_read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | asd1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | asd2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | asd3 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | asd4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | asd5 | 1 |

Надо найти количество непрерывно идущих единиц в поле is_read, начиная с конца таблицы.
Нужно сделать без применения оконных функций.
Для такой таблицы ответ должен быть : 2.

Comment: По какому признаку Вы сортируете таблицу, как понимаете "с конца таблицы"? Первичного ключа id в таблице нет?

Comment: *Нужно сделать без применения оконных функций.* Почему? Постгресс их поддерживает, так что нет вменяемой причины делать через задницу.

Comment: @Akina они тут как собаке пятая нога. Вопрос только в том, что такое "конец таблицы".

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 Почему это? классическое решение - через разность двух ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 под концом таблицы подразумевается последняя запись. Запрос для данной таблицы должен нам посчитать кол-во единиц начиная с конца

Comment: Начиная с конца до первого нуля. В данном случае последняя запись под id#5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берём максимальный id,  где 0, и считаем id после него:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM readed_books
WHERE id>(SELECT MAX(id) FROM readed_books WHERE is_read=0);
```

Comment: Но если вся таблица только с 1, то получаем баг.